# Insert Data From HTML to Django Template

Tags: python, django

I want to save data from HTML template into database Model. I want to override this toplaner_name, toplaner_avatar, toplaner_price everytime I submit the Form. The img and span tags are dynamically changing by JS

template

```
            <form method='POST'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="player-on-map toplaner">
                    <img class='img-on-map' src="{% static 'images/ago/img1.png' %}" alt="portrait-on-map">
                    <span class="nickname">Szygenda</span>
                    <span>Price: 1500</span>                                        
                </div>
                <button type='submit'>SAVE TEAM</button>
            </form>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'


class Team(models.Model):
    toplaner_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='k1ck/Ibo')
    toplaner_avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatar.png')
    toplaner_price = models.IntegerField()
```

JS

```
toplaners.forEach(toplaner => toplaner.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    toplaner_on_map.innerHTML = toplaner.innerHTML;
    toplaner_on_map.querySelectorAll('.btn, .position, .player-price').forEach(item => item.classList.add('hide'))
}))
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='profilecontent/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='profilecontent/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please provide your `views.py` file.

Comment: there is nothing there. I just hard coded all the data in HTML flie, i don't know if it's correct

Comment: In urls.py file also there are nothing?

Comment: I mean there is only render function, nothing else. Added urls.py to post

Comment: Team model is also in the same where your User model is?

Comment: I dont know what do you mean, so i updated a models.py file

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to make one URL in urls.py as below...

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='profilecontent/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='profilecontent/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),

    # Add new URL

    path('toplaner/', views.toplaner, name='toplaner'),


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then add `toplaner` view in `views.py` as below...

```
def toplaner(request):

    # Here you can get all the form data 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        field_name = request.POST.get('field_name_in_html_form')
        # Add all other required field here
```

Then you have to add action `url` in `form` as below...

```
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'toplaner' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="player-on-map toplaner">
    <img class='img-on-map' src="{% static 'images/ago/img1.png' %}" alt="portrait-on-map">
    <span class="nickname">Szygenda</span>
    <span>Price: 1500</span>                                        
  </div>
  <button type='submit'>SAVE TEAM</button>
</form>
```

Now, when you press submit button you will get your form data in `toplaner` view and at there you can write your further logic.

Comment: @Pamade, is this helpful or you have any confusions?